# Endless query on Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, backup, restore

A query of mine seems **endless** whereas it works in half a second on its **backup/restore version**.

`DELETE FROM`
tout.table a
`USING` tout.table b
`WHERE`
a.id < b.id
`AND` a.type = b.type;

I don't know what could be the issue there...any clue ?

(NB : I'm a superuser, and working on Postgresql)

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: I think its pretty obvious that your prod environment has some issues like - 1. data volume is significantly higher than backup. 2. some indexes etc. are missing from prod version. 3. Stats arent updated for tables in prod. 4. you ran this at a time when other big sqls are running consuming prod resources whereas backup version is relatively free.

Comment: It may be 2. and what do you mean by "stats arent updated" ?

Comment: If you run EXPLAIN on the query, do you get the same plan for both?

Comment: by 'stats not updated'i mean `analyze`. You can check analyze status by using `SELECT  relname, last_analyze FROM pg_stat_all_tables WHERE relname = 'table_name';`